# Programmatically change "Instant lock on power button" setting

Tags: android, configuration, adb

I'm pretty new to Android world so maybe I'm lacking some base concept. I'm writing a script (that will issued throught ADB shell) to update phone settings, typically here is a sample of what I want to achieve

```
su
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
update secure set value='Unlocking device message' where name='lock_screen_owner_info';
```

I want now to change the "Power button instantly lock" to be enable with my script (I've been searching in different sqlite databse but was unable to find anything relevant)

**Question :**

How to enable (or disable) the "Power button instantly lock" feature with a script ?

Comment: Do you want to set the lock screen to None?

Comment: In the GUI configuration you can't set the instant lock feature if you don't have a lockscreen so I'm assuming I want to keep it.

Comment: Set screen to stay active. If you want your app running and show status. Disable power button is not recommended

Comment: I don't want to disable the power button, you are mistaken with the feature that turn off and lock the screen when you press the power button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible to overwrite hardware button. But you can create onLockListener. See
http://chandan-tech.blogspot.com/2010/10/handling-screen-lock-unlock-in-android.html

Comment: I'm not really sure this will be usable for my project as it is very specific, but this sound like something acceptable, tahnks for the tip